# show data from mySQL result array returned by a function

Tags: php, mysql, resultset

I want to pass a mySQL result from a function and print the data.
How to do so ?

```
<?php
function showLatestItems()
 {
  $result = $this->query("SELECT aid,name,description,img,amount,strtdate,enddate FROM item WHERE enddate>now()");
  return $result;
/*      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
   echo $row[0].' '.$row[3].' '.$row[1].' '.$row[2].$row[4].$row[5].$row[6].'<br>';
*/
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trap the result resource and then fetch rows from it.  Based on the commented out code, we assume you have wrapped `mysql_query()` with a class method called `query()`.

```
$result = $yourclass->showLatestItems();
if ($result) {
  $rowset = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rowset[]  = $row;
  }
}

var_dump($rowset);
```

Comment: I hate var_dump, plz be nice :P

Comment: @Sourav `var_dump()` is only there to prove `$rowset` is an array.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @Sourav What `foreach`? There is none in your code or in mine.